# Field Validation with Checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I would like to know how to make the checkbox disabled if the input fields have not been prepended and are enabled when all fields have been filled out.
Thank you very much in advance.

```
 <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked" id="eula" name="eula" ng-click="sendSms()" required disabled="disabled"/>
            <span ng-class="{'text-white': invertTextColor}">Aceito os Termos e condições</span>
          <a ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed">ver os termos</a>
       </label>
 </div>
```

Comment: add some code that you have tried!!

Comment: OP please read [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms) and [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages/directive/ngMessages)

Comment: Improving the question a bit, I wanted the checkbox to be enabled only when all the fields of the form were filled, if any field was left unchecked the checkbox would be disabled.
I still do not have any code other than the one already posted but I would love to have them help me.